# What is the desired total low frequency response for a common emitter amplifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, frequency-response, common-emitter

For a common emitter the total low frequency response is different, depending on the values of input, output and bypass capacitors.

[image]

1. Three separate cutoff frequencies:

[image]

2. One cutoff frequency when all the three critical frequencies are the same:

[image]

Other combinations are possible too but I just mention two cases to illustrate the point.

Question:

What is the desired total low frequency for a common emitter amplifier like this? Assume that you are free to choose input, output and bypass capacitors as you want.

I know the purpose of each capacitor, but I want to focus on the frequency response instead of the general introduction about coupling and bypass capacitors.

Source: https://staff-old.najah.edu/sites/default/files/Chapter%2010.pdf

Comment: The question is impossible to answer. If the appication requires a particuar shape for the low-end rolloff, then you need to design to those requirements. Otherwise, it really doesn't matter -- you just need to make sure that all of them are below the lowest frequency of interest.

Comment: @hana: Do you mean "What cutoff frequency should I choose?" or do you mean "Which way is the correct way to set the cutoff frequency?"  The first depends on what your circuit requires - an audio amplifier might have a lower cutoff of 20Hz while an RF amplifier might have a cutoff of 20MHz.  The second might have various answers that depend on design decisions.

Comment: @JRE I want to know whether steep cut off is better or there is something that we want each case depending on the application.

Comment: First of all, you decide what the application needs, then you tailor the response of the mplifier to suit. 'Decide what the application needs' can be done by getting an amplifier with 'typical' capacitors, using it, and seeing whether it works in the application, and modifying it if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an audio frequency application the bandwidth would typically be limited to between 20 Hz and 20 kHz. The bandwidth limits are usually taken to be where the mid-band voltage gain has dropped by 3dB (the -3dB frequencies). This is where the power has dropped to/by 50%.

The common emitter amplifier circuit quite often includes 3 capacitors and therefore 3 high pass filters. 3 are required in order to fulfill the functionality of the amplifier (2 for dc block and 1 for increasing the gain). A side effect of this is that there is a -60 dB/decade (-18 dB/octave) low end roll-off. We don't intentionally design in this steep roll-off, it is a by-product of requiring the 3 capacitors for functionality.

So, if we go by the commonly accepted lower bandwidth limit as being where the signal has dropped by 3dB then we could design all three high pass 3 filters (choose the capacitor values) to have the same cut-off frequency of, say, 20 Hz. The 3 filters are effectively cascaded and each would give a 3dB drop at 20 Hz resulting in a 9 dB drop overall in signal level (as your second graph shows) at 20 Hz. To achieve the required -3 dB drop at 20 Hz we would then need to double the values of all 3 capacitors.